# Most number of game 7s played in a single playoffs

Tags: trivia, basketball, nba, postseason

In 2003, the NBA playoffs format was changed to have every single round played to a best-of-7 series, a format that is still used in today's NBA. From the 2003 Playoffs up to 2018, which season had the most number of game 7s played?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the [2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_NBA_Playoffs) and the [2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_NBA_Playoffs) NBA Playoffs had the most 7-game encounters, with 5 each.